# Action bar is not displaying in dijit dialog when using href attribute

Tags: dojo

I have the following code

```
var dlg = new dijit.Dialog({
        "title": "my dialog",
        "style": "width: 800px;",
        "id": "myDlg",
        "href":"some url"
    }).placeAt(dojo.body());


    var actionBar = dojo.create("div", {
        "class": "dijitDialogPaneActionBar"
    }, dlg.containerNode);

    new dijit.form.Button({
        "label": "Ok"
    }).placeAt(actionBar);
    new dijit.form.Button({
        "label": "Cancel"
    }).placeAt(actionBar);

    dlg.show();
```

with this code dialog is displaying with the url content but action bar is not showing,when i replace the href with some static content action bar is working fine.What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using "href" for the dojo Dialog, the content from the href loads as an ajax call every time the dialog is opened/showed. So, what happens here is your action bar and button are added first and then the href is loaded into the Dialog, which overwrites the existing action bar and the buttons -EVERYTIME!!
So, to achieve this, you can ensure that the action bar is added, once the href load is completed. For this, we use the Deferred object returned by the "show" method.

```
var dlg = new dijit.Dialog({
    "title": "my dialog",
    "style": "width: 800px;",
    "id": "myDlg",
    "href":"some url"
}).placeAt(dojo.body());

dlg.show().then(function() {
  if(dlg.firstTime) {
     var actionBar = dojo.create("div", {
        "class": "dijitDialogPaneActionBar"
     }, dlg.containerNode);

     new dijit.form.Button({
       "label": "Ok"
     }).placeAt(actionBar);
     new dijit.form.Button({
       "label": "Cancel"
     }).placeAt(actionBar);
     dlg.firstTime=true;
   }
});
```

But, i would suggest not to use this approach, because, every time, you create the action Bar and button widgets. So, i have added a parameter "firstTime" to dialog object to avoid it. SO, action bar and buttons are crated only one time. 
Hope this helps.